# Как можно просто выбрать элемент из массива

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
 Inventory.Instance.myships.Fraction.Select(x => x.Name == Missions[0].Fraction.ToString())
```

Вот здесь я бы хотел к этому элементу прибавить +=1, но select возвращает тип bool. Знаю что можно через цикл найти этот элемент по имени но я хотел бы проще одной строкой

Comment: `Select()` не возвращает `bool`, он возвращает то, что вы ему задаете, а именно, вы делаете сравнение `Name == Fraction` и это что у нас? Правильно, `bool`. Перепишите условие на тот вид, который вы хотите, а чтоб выбрать один объект по условию, исползуйте `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: 1) Не возвращает, а принимает условие, как в `if`, который был бы в `for`. 2) Что значит прибавить к `этому элементу` 1? это `int[]`? или у элемента есть поле количество? или индексу элемента массива?

Comment: Прибавить к ячейке массива ( который int[] ), которая равна определенному значению число.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Inventory.Instance.myships.Fraction.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == Missions[0].Fraction.ToString()).ReputationFr += Missions[0].RewardRep;
```